# How many different choices

Tags: combinatorics

From an $8 \times 8$ chessboard, how many different $4$ black and $4$ white cells can be selected so that neither eye is on the same row or column?
I try $32$ black and $32$ white then we choices $1$ black and $25$ black cell remian and choice second black cell $18$ black cell remain and third choice $13$ black cell remain sum up $32\times 25\times 18\times 13$ and i can't continue that problem

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "eye" ?

Comment: Eye means 8×8 chess board have 64 square  and we choice 4 white square,  4 black square but 1 choice square have row and column how many different several ways